# Python and Selenium with Whatsapp Web

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to make a bot that allows me to send any message for a lot of ppl.
through `web.whatsapp.com` i can do that, but my issue here with the class name :

[image]

this is Type a message's class, you can see it clearly : `_3FRCZ copyable-text selectable-text`, so my issue here that i cannot select it, idk why, i tried to select deffrent classes but still same issue.
here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
content = "Hi There"
phone = "+96657831111"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(f"https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone={phone}&text&source&data&app_absent")
input("Press Enter After Scanning..")
send = driver.find_element_by_class_name("_3FRCZ copyable-text selectable-text")
send.send_keys("Test")
```

**Notes:**

- for me i dont have to set geckdriver.
- my python verion is **3.8**

**EDIT:** I used xpath to do it `//div[@class='_3FRCZ copyable-text selectable-text']` and it worked, but with search box not messages box.
i realized that search box and message box has same class.

Comment: Try to use XPath instead of class finding, sometimes works better. Also, it would help to have a better image of the tag inspection.

Comment: @Nastor Same :(, ```selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //div[@id='div']//div[@class='_3FRCZ copyable-text selectable-text']```

Comment: Try to use WebDriverWait, perhaps the element isn't loaded at the time you're trying to access it.

Comment: @Nastor i hit enter when the page is loaded, however i tried to add wait and same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by using CSS Selector, You cannot use xpath or find element by class name, bc there is many elements using the same class name, so here is the best choice:

```
send = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[data-tab='6']")
send.send_keys(msg,Keys.ENTER)
```